# How to backup a G4 Max OS X 10.5

Tags: startup

I have an old Mac PowerBook G4 that I want to convert to Linux.

Before doing so I want to backup the hard drive.

My plan would be to make a full copy with `dd` (I've already backed up the data I the home folders). I know it's risky, but it's only going to be used in very unlikely situations.

However in order to minimize the risk I'd like to boot and keep the filesystem read-only, like in recovery mode on linux.

Is such a thing possible at all?

I am not aware of a live linux distro for PowerPC - otherwise it'd be an easier job.